# How to integrate html website template with spring MVC

Tags: javascript, html, css, spring, spring-mvc

This is my first time buying a online website template and plan to use it in my web application that develop by Spring MVC.

http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/templates/admin/

I want the entire template are place inside WEB-Inf folder.

It is means that I neeed to modify the entire template?
Below are my changes.

From `<link href="../../assets/global/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>`

To `<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/assets/global/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>`

Because I need to modify the whole template so Im asking whether what I doing now is the correct way?

below 1st one are the original folder structure.

the 2nd one is my own project. I moved all the CSS, JS out from web-inf folder so that the html page can get the static resources.

[image: the original template folder structure]

[image]

Comment: Rename your .html files to .jsp and place them inside WEB-INF\views folder.

Comment: @JamieWhite but how about those static resources? for example CSS and js, do I need to move them out from WEB-INF?

Comment: Place them files in the /resources folder

Comment: @JamieWhite thansk for your prompt reply. My last question is since we move those static resources to Resources folder that outside from WEB-INF, then in the jsp page all the path need to be modify? Can we remind those ("../") or those path actually already no longer valid.

Comment: Links in your jsp should be modified like so "/resources/foo.css".  Be sure to use the relevant taglib (c:url or spring:url) with the links